# How to build QT-JAMBI from Maven

Tags: java, qt, qt-jambi

I written some qt-jambi application on my eclipse with maven and i need to   build it as a executable file

How to build qt jambi application using maven

following is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.qt.main</groupId>
    <artifactId>QtTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.sitegraph.core.test.WebFrameInThread2</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>qtjambi</id>
            <name>qtjambi</name>
            <url>http://qtjambi.sourceforge.net/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>qtjambi</id>
            <name>qtjambi</name>
            <url>http://qtjambi.sourceforge.net/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.qtjambi</groupId>
            <artifactId>qtjambi</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2_01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.1_3</version>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

please help me 
thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, there is no up to date Maven packages as there has been no-one to maintain them, I suggest to use new packages from http://qtjambi.org

Comment: Hi @Smar ,is their any doc .to build qt jambi from  maven  pls do share me